# C# Lexer/Grammar/Parser for abstract statements

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, grammar, lexer

i need some ideas for the implementation of the following:

I have to create an UI, which allows the user to define SELECT statements on an abstract level. The user specifies the columns for his select, the order by , ...

Now i have a little problem with the WHERE.
The user should be able to choose just valid expressions / operators. That means i need something, which parses the current statement and tell me the next possible items.

An example:
The user is about to configure the where clause and starts with selecting a numeric field. The next step would be to define either an operator (+, -, *, /) or an comparison operator (>, <, <>, =).
In case the user choose an comparison operator, the next attribute has to be a static number, or another numeric field.
After this, the numeric field could be followed again by an operator, comparison operator, connector (AND, OR), ...
That means the syntax would be something like the following:

```
(<Value>|<Field>) <Operator> (<Value>|<Field>)+ (<Connector> <Field> <Operator> (<Value>|<Operator>)+)*
```

Therefore, what I’m looking for is a parser/lexer/grammar which allows me to define the syntax and is able to tell me what could be the next element. Sure, I could implement this myself, but i think it would be much cooler to do it with a grammar/parser/lexer.

Because I’m not realy into this, I hope you have an idea what tool to use for this. And give me a little direction what to search for.

Kind regards,

SyLuS

Comment: How does the UI look like, and how did you not run into wanting a parser earlier for the other parts of the query?

Comment: The UI shows the "Statement" in the upper part of the application. The lower ist to "create" the next element. So in case the user starts with a plain statement, he can choose between a Field and a static Value. After that he gets either a ComboBox with the fields or a numericTextBox to input the value. The user confirms the selection and then get the next choosable item in the lower part. For example Operators. So he is not able to choose something not supported. The main problem is, i need something to determine what the next element could be to change the UI based on the outcomes.

Comment: If you have a UI where you can select the things individually, then I don’t understand what you would need a parser for. Sure, you need to have some decision tree to determine the possible selections based on the previous input, but since you have no actual text input, there’s no need for parsers and grammars.

Comment: Maybe a parser is a bit oversized. But i dont know how a tree could help me out of this. A state machine could do the trick.